# why attribute :description returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, return

I can't find the error why attribute `:description` returns `nil`.
From `rails console`:

```
@book = Book.first
# Book Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books"   ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
#=> #<Book id: 1, title: "A Game of Thrones", description: nil, author: "George R. R. Martin ", created_at: "2016-09-01 13:27:09", updated_at: "2016-09-01 13:27:09">
```

`books_controller.rb`

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @books = Book.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end

  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if @book.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:description, :title,  :author)
  end

  def find_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.input :title, label: "Book Title" %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :author %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

'show.html.erb'

```
<h2><%= @book.title %></h2>
<h3><%= @book.author %></h3>
<h2><%= @book.description %></h2>
```

routs.rb

'Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
  root 'books#index'
end'

Comment: I suppose that you have tried to create a book from a form via your `BooksController`. Could you show the parameters that have been passed to your controller? You find them in your application's log file.

Comment: Try to create a new record and see even that doesn't have description. from Console

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using ? Do you have the "protected_attributes" gem declared in your Gemfile ? Do you have a "attr_accessible" in your `Book`model ?

Comment: doesn't look like there's anything wrong. Since you queried for `Book.first`, maybe that one doesn't have description in the first place? Can you check if there are books in the db that have description?

Comment: Hi Anna, welcome on SO. I flagged your question, because we might need more information (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe just your first book got wrong. Check `Book.last` to see if there the description got saved.

Comment: .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3 . I dont have "attr_accessible"  and "protected_attributes" gem . Maybe that is the reason, I have very old version.

Comment: The same with book.last. 
'@book= Book.last
  Book Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "books".* FROM "books"   ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<Book id: 2, title: "The Book of Eli", description: nil, author: "Geräten", created_at: "2016-09-01 13:42:45", updated_at: "2016-09-01 13:42:45">'      ..very strange

Comment: In your **Gemfile.lock**, which version of rails to you have? (here: `rails (5.0.0.1)`, the version is 5.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Check params hash passed to create action to create book. I think description would be missing.

Can you please paste the params hash here ?

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Where I can check params hash? Do you mean this :
'def book_params
       params.require(:book).permit(:description, :title,  :author)
      end'

Comment: no, if you are running app on your local in development mode, then check the log where your rails server is running. When you submit the form, log would be generating there. There you can see the params hash passed to that action.